# How to check if a number is an int or str python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create an if statement to check whether the number entered is an int or not. I don't know what to do as I am splitting an input (You enter 3d and a variable with 3 and one with d is made). I want it so that if you enter a letter then it doesn't produce an error message.

Here is the code in Question:

```
  while directionloop ==0:
    while DAmountLoop==0:
        direction=input('How do you want to move? Your answer should look like this 4u, this moves you up 4: ')
        directiondirection=str(direction[1])
        directionamount=(direction[0])
        if type(directionamount) != int:
            print('You need to enter a number for the amount you want to move')
        elif type(directionamount) == int:
            directionamount=int(direction[0])
            DAmountLoop=1
```

Comment: If you use "input", it will always give out "string" representation irrespective of the data type you enter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `direction` will always be `str`, because [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns `str`. Hence, the type of `direction[0]` is always also `str` (assuming `direction` is not empty). For this reason, `type(direction[0]) != int` will always be `True`.

However, strings have methods that check their contents. In this case, you can use [`str.isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric):

```
move = input('How do you want to move? ')
direction = direction[1]
amount = direction[0]
if not amount.isnumeric():
      print('You need to enter a number for the amount')
```

Also note that this will raise an `IndexError` if the input is shorter than 2 characters. You might want to make a specific check for that, or maybe use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to incorporate all of the matching logic.

Also, regarding your loop: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for a general recipe for validation of user input.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. I am going to sort some other stuff out in my code  then I will look at the validation post you linked, I have about 5 other parts of my code that have validation like what I posted.